# Pass Object from ViewData to jQuery not working (Error: Uncaught SyntaxError)

Tags: jquery

I try to pass List Category from ViewData to jquery but I'm not having any success:

View:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var timerid;
$("#new-title").on("input", function (e) {

var value = $(this).val();
if ($(this).data("lastval") != value) {
    $(this).data("lastval", value);


    clearTimeout(timerid);
    timerid = setTimeout(function () {

        var _catJson =JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(this.ViewData["Category"]))');//?????????

        alert(_catJson);
    }, 1000);
   }

  });
});
</script>

 @*test succsessful:*@
   @ViewData["Category"]
```

Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token K (anonymous function) @ (index):178

Comment: Is this all of your code ?